# $||x-2|+a|=4$ can have four distinct real solutions for $x$ then $a$ belongs to

Tags: calculus, functions

$||x-2|+a|=4$ can have four distinct real solutions for $x$ then $a$ belongs to

a)$(-\infty, -4)$

b)$(-\infty, 0]$

c)$[4, \infty)$

d) none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

To have $4$ solutions we need that $|x-2|+a$ assumes negative values.

Refer also to the sollowing sketch for

- $f(x)=|x-2|+a$

[image]

- $g(x)=|f(x)|=||x-2|+a|$

[image]

Comment: Is the answer a)(-infinity, -4)

Comment: @Alexallee Yes exactly! To see that let make a sketch for $|x-2|+a$, then realize that we need that this assumes negative values in order to have 4 solutions.

Comment: Thankyou sir 